# Xamarin.Android - Splash screen image is low quality

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an application in Xamarin.Forms with .NETStandard and I made a splash screen for the android application by coding something in the Android-specific project. It works, however for some reason, the splash screen's image quality seems lower to me than the original's. The original image is currently 150x150 pixels, I also tried to make the image in different sizes such as 100x100 pixels and 200x200 pixels but the issue persisted. 
The way I made it is this:

1. I created a theme within the styles.xml file:

   ```
   <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Within the Drawable folder I created a file called splash_screen.xml (splash is an image within the drawable folder):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item>
           <color android:color="@android:color/white"/>
       </item>
       <item>
           <bitmap
               android:src="@drawable/splash"
               android:tileMode="disabled"
               android:gravity="center"/>
       </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```
3. I coded an Activity in C# that consumes the Theme and is the MainLauncher for the application.

I believe this issue happens with more images in my application, meaning that the images' quality within the app seems lower and the images seem less sharp than the original images which are in the drawable folder.

In addition, I tried downloading Snapchat's APK file, and using the splash image there for my app for testing purposes because when I open that app on my device, its' splash screen's image looks high quality and sharp. However, even then, the quality seems lower in the splash screen of my application.

Answer (score 1):

You should take aware of the different android drawable sizes, look at the drawable folders:

- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- drawable-xxxhdpi

You should place your images with the same name in every folder with their respective size

36x36 for low-density (LDPI)

48x48 for medium-density (MDPI)

72x72 for high-density (HDPI)

96x96 for extra high-density (XHDPI)

144x144 for extra extra high-density (XXHDPI)

192x192 for extra extra extra high-density (XXXHDPI)